# ¿Como pasar datos de un archivo de texo a una estructura?

Tags: c++, archivo

Tengo que crear una estructura, pero para esto, tengo que hacer que por defecto ya hayan valores para la estructura, osea que si por ejemplo yo creo la estructura:

```
struct tintoreria{
    char id[4]{0};
    char ids[2]{0};
    char descripcion[30];
    float precio;
}tin[100][100];

void predeterminados(){
    tin[0][0].id='1111';
    tin[0][0].ids='01';
    tin[0][0].descripcion='blusa';
    tin[0][0].precio=100.00;

    tin[0][0].id='1111';
    tin[0][0].ids='02';
    tin[0][0].descripcion='camisa caballero';
    tin[0][0].precio=100.00;

    tin[0][0].id='1111';
    tin[0][0].ids='03';
    tin[0][0].descripcion='traje';
    tin[0][0].precio=100.00;

    tin[1][0].id='1112';
    tin[1][0].ids='01';
    tin[1][0].descripcion='blusa';
    tin[1][0].precio=100.00;

    tin[1][0].id='1112';
    tin[1][0].ids='02';
    tin[1][0].descripcion='camisa caballero';
    tin[1][0].precio=100.00;

    tin[1][0].id='1112';
    tin[1][0].ids='03';
    tin[1][0].descripcion='traje';
    tin[1][0].precio=100.00;

    tin[1][0].id='1112';
    tin[1][0].ids='04';
    tin[1][0].descripcion='pantalon de mezclilla';
    tin[1][0].precio=100.00;

    tin[1][0].id='1112';
    tin[1][0].ids='05';
    tin[1][0].descripcion='sabanas';
    tin[1][0].precio=100.00;

    tin[2][0].id='1113';
    tin[2][0].ids='01';
    tin[2][0].descripcion='zapato formal hombre';
    tin[2][0].precio=100.00;

    tin[2][0].id='1113';
    tin[2][0].ids='02';
    tin[2][0].descripcion='sandalias';
    tin[2][0].precio=100.00;

    tin[2][0].id='1113';
    tin[2][0].ids='03';
    tin[2][0].descripcion='zapato infante';
    tin[2][0].precio=100.00;

    tin[2][0].id='1113';
    tin[2][0].ids='04';
    tin[2][0].descripcion='Moicasines';
    tin[2][0].precio=100.00;
}
}
```

Comment: La estructura muere con el programa. Los datos persistentes se mantendrán en el fichero, no en la estructura. ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Eso para guardar no está mal... ahora... ¿Y para leer? ¿Y qué se supone que es `tin`? ¿De dónde vienen `a` y `b`?

Comment: Poner todo el codigo está muy largo

Comment: tin es la tienda

Comment: intente agregar el código pero no me dejó

Comment: a y b los usé como contadores, hice que iniciaran con 0, y así empezar a guardar en la fila 0 columna 0. Como es char, hice que la cadena este llena de numeros 0, y si tenía un numero, es que esa posición no se había usado, y si ya se usó, aumento a o b

Comment: hice que se llenaran los datos que queria por default solos pero no me deja copiar cadena de caracteres en otra cadena (ni siquiera sé si estoy diciendolo correctamente) actualizo la pregunta con el codigo

Comment: En la función que acabas de publicar, en la que das valores por defecto, estás metiendo diferentes datos en las mismas posiciones. Nunca cambias la segunda coordenada de la matriz. Das valores al objeto en la posión [0][0] y luego otra vez en la [0][0] en vez de en la [0][1], y así con todos.

Answer (score 1):

> Tengo que hacer que por default ya hayan valores para la estructura […] y yo tengo productos por default en un archivo de texto que me los agregue a la estructura y ahí se queden incluso si cierro el programa.

Siento tener que darte esta noticia, pero las cosas no funcionan así.

---

Los objetos de C++ existen en tres niveles:

- **Declaración**: Se dice que existen, pero no se dan detalles sobre el objeto.

  - Como analogía, imagina que te dicen "*Hay un nuevo modelo de coche Volkswagüen*<sup>1</sup>", sabes que el modelo existe, pero no sabes nada de él.
- **Definición**: Se dan los detalles del objeto.

  - Como analogía, imagina que te dan los planos del nuevo modelo Volkswagüen.
- **Instanciación**: Creas objetos.

  - Como analogía, imagina que fabricas el nuevo modelo de coche.

Cuando **Instancias** un objeto, el objeto ocupa un espacio en memoria y esa memoria que ocupa no ha obtenido ningún valor, ni de archivo ni de otro origen de [persistencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistencia_(inform%C3%A1tica)). No existe la carga de archivo-a-memoria *automágica*.

Si quieres asegurar la persistencia de tus datos, debes ser tú quien los persista. La estrategia que uses para hacerlo es cosa tuya, yo crearía unas funciones de `leer` y `escribir`:

```
std::list<tienda> leer(const std::string &archivo)
{
    std::list<tienda> resultado;

    if (std::ifstream datos{archivo})
    {
        while (datos)
        {
            tienda t;
            datos >> t.id;
            datos >> t.ids;
            datos >> t.producto;
            datos >> t.precio;
            resultado.push_back(t);
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No se pudo abrir " << archivo << '\n';

    return resultado;
}
```

```
void escribir(const std::list<tienda> &tiendas, const std::string &archivo)
{
    if (std::ofstream datos{archivo})
    {
        for (const auto &t : tiendas)
        {
            datos << t.id << '\n';
            datos << t.ids << '\n';
            datos << t.producto << '\n';
            datos << t.precio << '\n';
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No se pudo abrir " << archivo << '\n';
}
```

Por otro lado, puedes crear información que se guardará en el archivo ejecutable y estará disponible al arrancar el programa, para ello hagamos unas modificaciones a tu estructura `tintoreria`:

```
struct tintoreria{
    std::string id;
    std::string ids;
    std::string descripción;
    float precio;
};
```

Haz que los elementos de texto de la estructura sean cadenas de texto (`std::string`), después en el punto de entrada puedes crear una lista de `tintorería`:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

struct tintoreria{
    std::string id;
    std::string ids;
    std::string descripción;
    float precio;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<tintoreria> tintorerias
    {
    //    id      ids   descripción              precio
        { "1111", "01", "blusa",                 100.f },
        { "1111", "02", "camisa caballero",      100.f },
        { "1111", "03", "traje",                 100.f },
        { "1112", "01", "blusa",                 100.f },
        { "1112", "02", "camisa caballero",      100.f },
        { "1112", "03", "traje",                 100.f },
        { "1112", "04", "pantalon de mezclilla", 100.f },
        { "1112", "05", "sabanas",               100.f },
        { "1113", "01", "zapato formal hombre",  100.f },
        { "1113", "02", "sandalias",             100.f },
        { "1113", "03", "zapato infante",        100.f },
        { "1113", "04", "Moicasines",            100.f },
    };

    // …
    // Hacer cosas
    // …

    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Marca de coche inventada, cualquier parecido con la realidad es casual.

Comment: Como dice @PaperBirdMaster al abrir el programa se deberían leer los archivos de texto con los datos por defecto y cargarlos en memoria con las funciones que te muestra. Así cada vez que uses el programa tendrás disponible la información.

Comment: Bueno... verán, para quitarme el problema hice que se llenaran los datos que queria por default solos pero no me deja copiar cadena de caracteres en otra cadena (ni siquiera sé si estoy diciendolo correctamente) actualizo la pregunta con el codigo

Answer (score 1):

> pero no me deja copiar cadena de caracteres en otra cadena

En cualquier línea como la siguiente:

```
tin[0][0].descripcion='traje';
```

Tienes 2 errores de bulto:

1. Las comillas simples se usan para **caracteres**, no para cadenas de caracteres. Las cadenas de caracteres usan comillas dobles:

   ```
   tin[0][0].descripcion = "traje";
   ```
2. Las cadenas de tipo `char*` o `char[]` **no se pueden copiar con el operador de asignación**. El motivo es que ambos tipos se tratan como punteros... es decir, en el caso de `char*` conseguirías que varios variables apuntasen a la misma cadena, mientras que en el caso de `char[]`, como el puntero no se puede modificar, el compilador se queja y con razón. Para solucionar este problema lo más cómodo, en C++`es usar la clase`std::string` en vez de cadenas de caracteres al estilo C:

   ```
   struct tintoreria{
       std::string id;
       std::string ids;
       std::string descripcion;
       float precio;
   };
   ```

   A diferencia de `char[]`, la clase `std::string` trae consigo una serie de ventajas que facilitan enormemente su uso, como no tener que preocuparse por un tamaño máximo, no lidiar con memoria dinámica, el código queda más natural, ...

   ```
   std::cout << "Dime tu nombre";
   std::string nombre;
   std::cin >> nombre; // El usuario puede introducir lo que le de la gana

   std::string saludo = "Hola " + nombre; // Concatenamos cadenas
   std::cout << saludo;
   ```