# ¿Qué pasa en este código?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Esta parte de mi código es para que me guarde automaticamente unos datos por default pero cuando hago el cout de hasta abajo salen más cosas que no deberían. yo pido que me imprima el ids pero me imprime la descripcion tambien.

Esta parte de mi código es para que me guarde automaticamente unos datos por default pero cuando hago el cout de hasta abajo salen más cosas que no deberían

Esta parte de mi código es para que me guarde automaticamente unos datos por default pero cuando hago el cout de hasta abajo salen más cosas que no deberían

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct tintoreria{
    char id[4];
    char ids[2];
    char descripcion[30];
    float precio;

}tin[50][50];

int main(){
    strcpy(tin[0][0].id,"1111");
    strcpy(tin[0][0].ids,"01");
    strcpy(tin[0][0].descripcion,"blusa");
    tin[0][0].precio=100.00;

    strcpy( tin[0][1].id,"1111");
    strcpy(tin[0][1].ids,"02");
    strcpy(tin[0][1].descripcion,"camisa caballero");
    tin[0][1].precio=100.00;

    strcpy( tin[0][2].id,"1111");
    strcpy(tin[0][2].ids,"03");
    strcpy(tin[0][2].descripcion,"traje");
    tin[0][2].precio=100.00;

    strcpy(tin[1][0].id, "1112");
    strcpy(tin[1][0].ids,"01");
    strcpy(tin[1][0].descripcion,"blusa");
    tin[1][0].precio=100.00;

    strcpy(tin[1][1].id, "1112");
    strcpy(tin[1][1].ids,"02");
    strcpy(tin[1][1].descripcion,"camisa caballero");
    tin[1][1].precio=100.00;

    strcpy(tin[1][2].id, "1112");
    strcpy(tin[1][2].ids,"03");
    strcpy(tin[1][2].descripcion,"traje");
    tin[1][2].precio=100.00;

    strcpy(tin[1][3].id, "1112");
    strcpy(tin[1][3].ids,"04");
    strcpy(tin[1][3].descripcion,"pantalon mezclilla");
    tin[1][3].precio=100.00;

    strcpy(tin[1][4].id, "1112");
    strcpy(tin[1][4].ids,"05");
    strcpy(tin[1][4].descripcion,"sabanas");
    tin[1][4].precio=100.00;

    strcpy(tin[2][0].id, "1113");
    strcpy(tin[2][0].ids, "01");
    strcpy(tin[2][0].descripcion,"zapato formal hombre");
    tin[2][0].precio=100.00;

    strcpy(tin[2][1].id, "1113");
    strcpy(tin[2][1].ids, "02");
    strcpy(tin[2][1].descripcion,"sandalia");
    tin[2][1].precio=100.00;

    strcpy(tin[2][2].id, "1113");
    strcpy(tin[2][2].ids, "03");
    strcpy(tin[2][2].descripcion,"zapato infante");
    tin[2][2].precio=100.00;

    strcpy(tin[2][3].id, "1113");
    strcpy(tin[2][3].ids, "04");
    strcpy(tin[2][3].descripcion,"moicasines");
    tin[2][3].precio=100.00;

    cout<<tin[0][0].ids<<"\n";

}
```

Comment: Debes aumentar el tamaño del buffer en `char id[4]` y `char ids[2]`. Es decir, debes dejar un espacio para el caracter nulo.

Comment: como le aumento el buffer?

Comment: Osea solo haz esto `char id[5]` y `char ids[3]`

Comment: Tienes dos respuestas ([una](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/308451/2742) y [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/308455/2742)) en otra pregunta en que tienes dudas sobre el mismo código en que se te aconseja pasar a `std::string` en lugar de usar arreglos de caracteres. Eso resuelve algunos de tus problemas.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como pasar datos de un archivo de texo a una estructura?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/308449/como-pasar-datos-de-un-archivo-de-texo-a-una-estructura)

Answer (score 0):

Un array de 4 caracteres (char id[4];) permite almacenar hasta cuatro caracteres.
Un cadena de texto ("hola") es un array de caracteres, pero con una condición especial, la última posición contiene en caracter 0 (no este 0, sino el valor cero de la tabla ASCII, que se puede representar por '\0'). Eso quiere decir que el array que almacena la cadena "hola" es realmente de 5 elementos, donde sus elementos son: 'h', 'o', 'l', 'a', '\0'

Por ejemplo, la cadena de texto más corta "", es un array de un elemento '\0'.
Por lo que si quieres guardar una cadena de texto de cuatro caracteres necesitas que el array sea de cinco.

Por ello debes hacer los arrays id de 5, y el array ids de 3:
char id[5];
char ids[3];
Lo mismo deberías hacer para descripción, el array debería ser de 31 si quieres guardar una cadena de texto de longitud máxima 30.